# MySQL Table id increments though nothing is inserted

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert new data into my table if it doesn't exist yet. So I'm using:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (OrderId, OrderStatus, PaymentMethod) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$statement->execute(array($OrderID, $OrderStatus, $PaymentMethod));
```

Which works pretty well. But even if nothing has been inserted, the _id (which is set to auto increment) will increase by one. I get the new data from an API. So if there are "old" orders which are already in my DB, those old ones will increment my _id everytime the server runs the script - but I only want to increase the id-value for NEW orders.

Comment: I wouldn't make much assumptions with auto increments or rely much on auto increment values being contiguous. There are plenty of cases where it could happen to avoid concurrent access to db

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid this without explicitly checking if the row already exists before running the `INSERT` query, not even with `INSERT IGNORE`. The reason is that a new ID is issued from `AUTO_INCREMENT` before anything else happens in order to maintain your data's integrity.

I learned this the hard way when an hourly cron rife with `INSERT IGNORE` chewed through 16 million IDs in a month after some some dingbat used a `MEDIUMINT` to save *one whole byte per row*.

If you ever have the same problem you'd best pray that that ID column isn't used in a foreign key constraint.

Secondly, if you're not using `INSERT IGNORE` then every single plain `INSERT` query you run from the code you've posted is also generating an error, which to me screams "this guy isn't checking for errors at all" which is super mondo bad.